# Google Earth Engine - NASA/NEX Climate Data

Tags: climate, google-earth-engine

I am working with the NASA/NEX-DCP30 downscaled climate data.

Ideally, I would like to set a threshold for two bands - pr (precipitation) and tasmax (maximum temperature) and filter it to display where those are *both* met in a given year (e.g. tasmax > 300 AND pr < .0001 for 1995) both visually and ultimately export as a raster and do some charts of how many times it occurred in a year.

Here was my best attempt, maps look nice but it doesn't account for both pr AND tasmax in the same layer...

```js
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/NEX-DCP30')
    .filterDate('1994-01-01', '1995-12-31')
var maxtemp = collection.select(['tasmax']);
var precipitation = collection.select(['pr']);
Map.addLayer((maxtemp),
    {'min': 286, 'max': 310, palette: '000000, 00FF00'}, 'MaxTemp');
Map.addLayer((precipitation),
    {'min': 0, 'max': .000025, palette: '0000FF, FF0000'}, 'Precipitation');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach that you want to take is:

1. Define your collection of daily images.
2. Write a function that works on individual images, and masks out data that does not meet the criteria you provide.
3. Map the function across all images in your collection.
4. Display a count of the data that is not masked out.

The following Earth Engine JavaScript code implements this logic:

var tasmax_threshold = 300;
    var pr_threshold = 0.0001;

```js
// Create a function that masks out data that does not meet the
// specified thresholds.
var MaskDailyImage = function(img) {
  var mask = img.select('tasmax').gt(tasmax_threshold)
                .and(img.select('pr').lt(pr_threshold));
  return img.updateMask(mask); 
};

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/NEX-DCP30')
    .filterDate('1995', '1996');
// Map the masking function over all images in the collection.
var filtered = collection.map(MaskDailyImage);
// Create a mask for where there is any valid data.
var data_mask = collection.count().gt(0);
var filtered_count = filtered.count();
// Make sure zero counts are not masked out.
filtered_count = filtered_count.mask(data_mask.mask());
Map.addLayer(
  filtered_count,
  {bands:'tasmax', 'min': 0, 'max': 300, palette: '000000, FFFFFF'},
  'count of occurrence'
);
```

This following link is a shortcut for producing the code above: https://code.earthengine.google.com/065b73a54c25127fb640b875fe7da676

Comment: Thank you so much for such a helpful and clear response. I truly appreciate it.